# Accessing child from parent

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the models defined below:

```
class PrimaryAsset(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=200)

class Service(PrimaryAsset):
    description = models.Charfield(max_length=200)

class Website(PrimaryAsset):
    url = models.Charfield(max_length=200)


class AssetLinks(models.model):
    high = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryAsset)
    low = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryAsset)


AssetLinks.objects.filter(high=212)[0].low
```

When I do the filter above, how can I know which instance the objects is (website or service)? Also, is there a way to avoid an N+1 query using `prefetch_related` in a way that it gets all the child information as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even use `select_related` instead of `prefetch_related`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
asset = AssetLinks.objects.filter(high=212).select_related(
    'high__service', 'high__website',
    'low__service', 'low__website',
)[0]

#check for service/website
service = getattr(asset.high, 'service', None)
website = getattr(asset.high, 'website', None)
```

Comment: `Service` and `Website` [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) from `PrimaryAsset` and `AssetLinks` has `FK`s to `PrimaryAsset`